# vb.net timer logic (nesting timers)

Tags: vb.net, timer

I've written an app in VB.net that captures data from my PicoScope USB oscilloscope.

It polls the 'scope using a timer, so for example it will poll every 'x' seconds (which is working fine).

However - I also want an option to be able to have this 'x' poll to only run for 'y' minutes, and then stop polling.

I'm having a problem understanding how to nest the timing loops (if nesting is the right option).

This is my code;

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Label6.Text = Counter.ToString
        Call ReadScope()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Label6.Text = Counter.ToString
        ' Call sub
        ' need to call routine below elsewhere
        ' I think this is where I need to loop timer 1

    End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click.

' THIS WORKS

 If y <= 0 Then
            ' here I want standard capture
            Call CaptureInterval()

        Else
            ' then here I want capture interval
            Call CaptureDuration()

        End If

End Sub

' AND THEN I HAVE (which works)
' This is the 'x' timer

Private Sub CaptureInterval()
        ' this works
        If x <= 0 Then
            MsgBox("Capture interval not set!")
            Return
        End If
        Me.Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x).TotalMilliseconds
        Me.Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

' then I have the 'y' timer

   Private Sub CaptureDuration()
        ' this doesn't work
        MsgBox("Reached capture duration")
        ' might need a while timer2 here...
        Me.Timer2.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(y).TotalMilliseconds
        Me.Timer2.Start()
        ' Me.TimerStop()
        ' I think I need the code below in this loop.
        ' or just Call CaptureInterval() as below - but in this timer loop
        ' Call CaptureInterval()
' THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK!
        If x < 1 Then
            MsgBox("Capture interval not set!")
            Return
        End If
        While Me.Timer1.Interval < y
            Me.Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x).TotalMilliseconds
            Me.Timer1.Start()
        End While

    End Sub

Public Sub ReadScope()
' contains the processing to read the scope data
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example - there is a form with a single timer and then add the code below. In order to satisfy:

> I also want an option to be able to have this 'x' poll to only run for
>   'y' minutes, and then stop polling.

You just need to set `_MaxTicks` = (Y minutes * 1000) / `_TickInterval`.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _MaxTicks As Integer = 10
    Private _TickCount As Integer = 0
    Private _TickInterval As Integer = 1000

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Timer1.Interval = _TickInterval
        AddHandler Me.Timer1.Tick, AddressOf TimerTick
        _TickCount = _MaxTicks
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TimerTick()
        Debug.Print(_TickCount)
        If _TickCount = 0 Then
            Me.Timer1.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Time elapsed is roughly {0} ms", _MaxTicks * _TickInterval))
        End If
        _TickCount -= 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks - I found a similar solution which I have detailed above.

Comment: Looking at your solution on a relaxed Sunday morning suggests it's far more elegant than mine! I'll give it a go. Thank you,.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the timer code.

Variable 'y' is the test duration, which I can select using a numeric control.

If it's greater than '0' then the if loop is activated, and will stop the timer when the counter (IntervalTimer) matches 'y'.

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        IntervalTimer = IntervalTimer + 1
        Label6.Text = IntervalTimer.ToString

        If y >= 0 Then
            If IntervalTimer.ToString = y Then
                Me.Timer1.Stop()
            End If
        End If

        Call ReadScope()
    End Sub
```

Please note that the variable "Counter" in the code posted originally has changed to "IntervalTimer".